# How to create public calculation function that returns calculated value?

Tags: java, android, function

I would like to create public function, that will be used to calculate some value. I would like the value to be the output of the function, for example:

```
public void Calculation(...)
{
x = y+z/2 +i;
if(x >= 10)
{
calculation = 1;
}
else if(x < 10)
{
calculation = 0;
}
}
```

and than, to use it in some other place like:

```
int final = Calculation(...);
```

My calculation is a lot more bigger, so I don't like placing it on many places, I just want it to be on one place, and to return the value, because I need to use it more times. How can I make this? Thanks in advice.

Comment: You can't use a variable named `final`, this is a java keyword, and this calculation function has a `void` return value.... if you want to set a variable to a function call it needs to return the type for the given variable.

Comment: Ah, ok. xD I just typed the first thing that came to my mind xD

Comment: @НиколаПејић: It's important to give *realistic* examples. It's really not clear at the moment whether you don't know how to write a method which returns something, or whether your question is about something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're assigning a value to a variable, and declaring that your method doesn't return anything. Instead, you should just make it return the result:

```
public int calculate(...)
{
    int x = y+z/2 +i;
    if(x >= 10)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(x < 10)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 2; // Or whatever...
}
```

If the method doesn't need any *state*, you can make it a static method, so you can call it without an instance of the declaring class.

If you need the method just within the type itself; make it private. If you need it within the type hiearchy, make it protected. If you need it within the same package, give it the default access (no modifiers). If you need it everywhere, make it public.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new class called Util, and add the method;

```
public class Util {

    public static int Calculation(int x, int y, int z, int i) {
        int calculation=0;
        x = y + z / 2 + i;
        if (x >= 10) {
            calculation = 1;
        } else if (x < 10) {
            calculation = 0;
        }

        return calculation;
    }
}
```

Then from anywhere, you can call it like this;

```
int final_value = Util.calculation(1,2,3,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your method static and put it in some utility class.

```
public class CalculationUtils
{
    public static someReturnType yourMethod (...someParams...)
    {
        ....
        return ...
    }

}
```

Then you can access it from any other class using :

```
someReturnType varName = CalculationUtils.yourMethod(...params...);
```

Comment: I forgot to add, I am very new to android , and to development, so I don't know how to do it... xD

Answer (score 1):

Declare a class called `Utils`, this class will have a static method that can be called anywhere. Like this:

```
public class Utils
{
   public static Integer calculationMethod(params)
   {
       int calculation = 0;
       x = y+z/2 +i;
       if(x >= 10)
       {
           calculation = 1;
       }
       else if(x < 10)
       {
           calculation = 0;
       }

       return calculation;
   }
}
```

You can call this method inside the Utils class or outside the class.

1. Calling inside the Utils class:

   `Integer value = calculationMethod(params);`
2. Calling outside the Utils class:

   `Integer value = Utils.calculationMethod(params);`

For more information about static methods see [this](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/methods/50static-methods.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Utitlity
{
   public int static calculateAndReturnSomeValue(int x, int y, int z, int i)
   {
       //do some calculations here

       int calculation = 0;

       x = y+z/2 +i;

       if(x >= 10)
       {
          calculation = 1;
       }
       else if(x < 10)
       {
          calculation = 0;
       }

       return calculation;
   }

}
```

Now when you want to use it, you can do this:

```
int result = Utility.calculateAndReturnSomeValue(2, 4, 6, 9);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: you also need `int calculation = 0;` otherwise you'd get a null pointer from this code...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks people! I did it. I use it like this now, it seems to work...

```
 public int Izracunavanje(int rezultat)
    {

      ...

        rezultat = ...;
    return rezultat;
}
```

and when I want to call it in other functions , it is like:

```
rezultat = Izracunavanje(rezultat);
```

Thank you, so much!